# want to get all dates but when there is one or more TDBUY = 1 then this date@TDBUY=0 not

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a date column and a column named TDBUY (which can be 0 or 1). Now I do following:

```
     SELECT tradedate,aktienstat.TDBuyPerfection,count(*) as cc from
     aktienstat   group by TradeDate,TDBuyPerfection  HAVING cc >= '0' ORDER
     BY TradeDate desc limit 100;
```

And get:
[image]

I don`t want to display f.e. the 2018-02-08 or 2018-02-07  with 0 count (line 1 and line 3) because there are 1 count with 1 each. But if no TDBUY then the date should be displayed with 0 count.

Can anyone here tell me please how to do it?
THANKS

Edit: It works also fine with SUM instead of Count.

```
     SELECT tradedate,aktienstat.TDBuyPerfection,sum(aktienstat.TDBuyPerfection) as summe from
 aktienstat   group by TradeDate ORDER
 BY TradeDate desc limit 100;´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try doing this via a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    tradedate,
    CASE WHEN cnt_1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TDBuyPerfection,
    CASE WHEN cnt_1 = 0 THEN cnt_0 ELSE cnt_1 END AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT
        tradedate,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN TDBuyPerfection = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_0,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN TDBuyPerfection = 1 THEN 1 END) AS cnt_1
    FROM aktienstat
    GROUP BY tradedate
) t;
```

The pivot trick works here because it brings the zero and one counts into a single record.  There, it is relatively easy to test both counts.  In your current form, it is much harder to check the counts.

The demo below shows that zero buy dates appear with only the zero count, while dates having a buy count show only the buy data.

### Demo

Comment: or I use sum() instead of count() like  my edited question

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair Yes, you may do that, but keep in mind that this syntax would really only run on MySQL, and not most other databases. Actually, the COUNT expression I used is shorter than the same logic expressed with SUM, because in the former case we can eschew the ELSE condition.

Comment: thanks for your great comment. Your solution is very sophisticated! :)